# How to create executable file for Mac

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono

I have developed an application for Windows. But now I need to run it on OS X, so I can develop it on Mono framework.
But I don't how to build a executable file for the MAC OS.
Please give me some ideas.

Comment: The easiest way (if not the cheapest) would be to get a Mac.

Comment: If you developed you exe in mono then it would most certainly run on a Mac. Just run "mono your.exe" without quotes. It may take a while to start the first time.

Comment: Use virtual machines like "VMware Workstation".

Comment: Thanks Tien Dinh  Yes I would try it again . b'cos I had errors when I was trying to execute the exe in terminal (ex : mono myexename.exe) . So I will need to check my sourcecode and try it again

Comment: Thanks  xwpedram , I won't be able to run virtual machine on my MAC . I will need standalone application which can be run on mac os.

Comment: I'm getting this error on very simple application. Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Container ---> System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Container:gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to execute .exe which is build on Mono . 
It ca be execute simply

> mono exeName.exe

But if you are getting an error you may need to add the line given in below to the profile file which is located in

> /etc/profile

add  this line

> export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/LIBRARY/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/lib:/usr/lib